# (Swift) How to create global array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create a global `array` (of items in a cart) in Swift so that I can access it from different pages.

Can you please point me in the right direction? declaring an array under the import statement in AppDelegate gives me the "unresolved Identifier" issue.

What should I use? How can I accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In swift you can encapsulate variables in a struct and you can access them anywhere.

```
struct GlobalVariables {
    static var globalString = "MyString"
}
```

To call it

```
// Get value
let str = GlobalVariables.globalString

// Set value
GlobalVariables.globalString = "New value"
```

Checkout the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_382) for more information.

Comment: I can't upvote you yet, but this solution totally works! Thank you :)

Comment: Np, glad to help @timtamsyoyo

Answer (score 1):

first controller: declare variable

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    var test2 = 5

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

second controller call variable

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var myCustomViewController: ViewController = ViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(myCustomViewController.test2)
    } }
```